# setText - cannot resolve method

Tags: android

Pretty sure this is a stupid question but I can't figure this out.

I am trying to get an integer returned by a datepicker to a string. This code works where `day` is the integer of interest

```
dateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dateButton);
dateButton.setText((Integer.toString(day));
```

This code gives me the error that cannot resolve method setText

```
String yearString = "";
yearString.setText(Integer.toString(year));
```

I don't understand why I cant convert the int to a string unless I use a view?

Comment: use Integer.valueOf()

Comment: What is yearString here?

Comment: YearString is null. Its what i want to be set to the year as a string

Comment: The class String (which yearString is an instance of) has no method called 'setText'. When you say 'This code gives me the error' you mean that you have a compilation problem. The part about the Button (which does have 'setText' method) is irrelevant. The way to set a String value is : yearString = Integer.toString(day) - or several other options.

Comment: Yep realised the button was not the problem but had it there for context to show there was no bigger problem. This is the solution and will mark as such if you make it an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this, what you want to do.

```
int year = 2014;
String yearString = Integer.toString(year);
```

Because stText mthod is only for setting text on certain views on android likeTextView, EditText, Button.

Answer (score 3):

You can set integer value by following ways if day is an integer value,

```
dateButton.setText(day+"");
```

or by

```
dateButton.setText(String.valueOf(day));
```

or

```
dateButton.setText(Integer.toString(day));
```

Comment: All of this works on the datebutton but throws an error on the yearString which is my problem

Comment: What is the value of yearString? It is and integer or string? And if it is null then then before setting it, validate it once. If it is null then set blank string.

Answer (score 1):

```
dateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dateButton);
dateButton.settext(Interger.Valueof(day));
```

Comment: Datebutton is not the problem. It works in my code. yearString is the problem

Comment: String yearString = "";
yearString.setText(Integer.toString(yearString));              because you are Passing String to tostring() which is not allowed in java ....Type cast error here you are doing Integer.toString which mean tostring aspect INteger not String

Answer (score 1):

you have to instantiate the object before you call it view I am new to this also
So this

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.now_playing_text)).setText(trackTitle)
```

Becomes

```
TextView Title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.now_playing_text);
Title.setText(trackTitle);
```

setText must be applied on an a class that contains in it or it supper classes the setText method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
dateButton.setText((Integer.toString(day));
```

Try this

```
dateButton.setText(day+"");
```